# How to list files inside public folder?

Tags: php, curl

I have a persistent volume defined in server under `www/public/images/logo/`

I want to list all the files inside that folder. So far I have done following lines with no luck.

```
public function getFiles($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}


    $url = 'https://myurl.de/images/logo/';

    $data = $this->getFiles($url);
```

Can anybody please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are want to list all files on same server then you can use php function scandir();

If you are want to list all files on remote server then you need to connect it using ftp like below code.

```
    $connection = ftp_connect("HOST_NAME");
    $login = ftp_login($connection, "FTP_USERNAME","FTP_PASSWORD");
    ftp_pasv($connection, true);
    $fileList = ftp_nlist($connection,'DIRECTORY_ON_FTP');
    ftp_close($connection);
```

Comment: I used scandir but this is giving me false

Comment: For scandir function, you have to use path instead of URL. If still not work then post code here.

Comment: I did `$files2 = scandir('./www/public/images/news');`

Comment: check path by echo __DIR__; statement and pass parameter accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean `echo __DIR__;` ? This return `/www/src/Controller`

Comment: Then add this scandir("/www/public/images/news");
If still doesn't work then I need to check the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234402/discussion-between-hirak-sheth-and-s-s).

Comment: scandir('./images/news'); Finally this worked. Thanks man